# How to enforce private parameters in constructors in Kotlin with ArchUnit?

Tags: kotlin, archunit

I have this class:

```
class CreateUser(private val userRepo: UserRepository) {

    fun execute(user: User) {
        userRepo.save(user)
    }
}
```

I have this test:

```
@Test
fun `private dependencies at constructors`() {
    constructors()
        .that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().resideInAPackage("users.usecases..")
        .should().haveModifier(JavaModifier.PRIVATE)
        .check(classes)
}
```

but it does not work since I'm targeting constructors and not their parameters.

Is it possible to target these fields in Kotlin constructors? I'd like to **enforce that the `private` keyword is used to mark all constructor parameters** (in this case, only userRepo) .

Comment: Hi Luís, not sure what you mean with `userRepo becomes a field/getter/setter`. What you're doing here is creating a new constructor, but you didn't create a setter (it's a val).

Comment: Do you want to test for private constructor or private field ?

Comment: You appear to be testing if the constructor is private in the test case, but you did not mark the constructor private.  Is this what you are intending?

Comment: I'd like to enforce that the `private` keyword is used to mark all constructor parameters (in this case, only `userRepo`)